# Pandas date_range method

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to create a time series of dates using business day frequency beginning on August 1,2020 (not a b.d.) until August 31, 2020.  I tried the following code but received an unexpected result.

```
In [1]: Import pandas as pd
In [2]: pd.date_range(start = '01-08-2020', end = '31-08-2020',freq='B')

Out[2]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-08', '2020-01-09', '2020-01-10', '2020-01-13',
           '2020-01-14', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-16', '2020-01-17',
           '2020-01-20', '2020-01-21',
           ...
           '2020-08-18', '2020-08-19', '2020-08-20', '2020-08-21',
           '2020-08-24', '2020-08-25', '2020-08-26', '2020-08-27',
           '2020-08-28', '2020-08-31'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=169, freq='B')
```

Why does the time series begin on January 8th, 2020 instead of August 3rd, 2020 yet it ends at the correct date of August 31st, 2020?  The start date is interpreted as %m-%d-%Y yet the end date is interpreted as %d-%m-%Y which is very confusing.

Why aren't both the start date and the end date interpreted as per my intention of %m-%d-%Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- With [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html), the expected format for `start` and `end`, is `datetime` like.
- With your current implementation, I get a DatetimeIndex starting on `'2020-01-08'` and ending on `'2020-11-09'` (this is Nov 11).

  - However, the date ranges were changed with this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63853432/2).
- Correct datetime format is `%Y-%m-%d`, for year, month, and day.
- With a format like `'1/1/2018'`, month is interpreted first.
- `(start = '01-08-2020', end = '31-08-2020',freq='B')` is ambiguous

  - The API knows, no months are `31`, so it swaps the selection.
  - Ambiguous formats will result in misinterpretation.
- [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) has a `dayfirst` and `yearfirst` parameter.
- [pandas User Guide: Time series / date functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#time-series-date-functionality)

  - [Generating ranges of timestamps](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#generating-ranges-of-timestamps)

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# this
pd.date_range(datetime(2020, 8, 1), datetime(2020, 8, 31), freq='B')

# or this
pd.date_range(start='2020-08-01', end='2020-08-31', freq='B')

DatetimeIndex(['2020-08-03', '2020-08-04', '2020-08-05', '2020-08-06',
               '2020-08-07', '2020-08-10', '2020-08-11', '2020-08-12',
               '2020-08-13', '2020-08-14', '2020-08-17', '2020-08-18',
               '2020-08-19', '2020-08-20', '2020-08-21', '2020-08-24',
               '2020-08-25', '2020-08-26', '2020-08-27', '2020-08-28',
               '2020-08-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```